# DVD authoring burning

Tags: video

I am looking for a player that i can burn to a disk.
I used to have this facility when i used DVDit le but lost the serial number. I was able to write video files to disk along with a player - thus end user was guaranteed to be able to play disk.
Can anyone help ?

Thanks.

Feargal

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of free, open-source, video players, but VLC springs to mind as one of the best for being cross-platform. You could freely include versions for Windows, Mac, Linux, iOs, Android, as well as OSes you've never heard of like QNX Sylable, OS2, Solaris and three flavours of BSD.